# "Dewa" for changing the subject

Tags: word-choice

If someone is speaking about a subject that  you're not comfortable with can you say "dewa" to change topic?

Answer (score 3):

No. では (or それでは) is like "Okay then, ..." which is primarily used to *continue* the current topic based on what was said. では is also used to return to the main issue after digressing, like "Okay now, (let's start ...)".

If you want to switch to a totally new topic, you should use ところで (≒"by the way"), それより (≒"before that"), etc.